# Levi civita to express determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

I cannot wrap my head around this identity for a 3 by 3 Matrix:

$\sum_{l,m,n = 1}^{3} \varepsilon^{lmn} a_{li}a_{mj}a_{nk} = \varepsilon^{ijk}$det$M$

I have tried proving this using the Leibniz formula
$\varepsilon^{ijk}\det(A)=\varepsilon^{ijk}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal S_n}\text{sign}(σ)a_{1σ(1)}a_{2σ(2)}a_{3σ(3)} = \sum_{\sigma\in\mathcal S_n}\varepsilon^{ijk}\varepsilon^{\sigma(1)\sigma(2)\sigma(3)}a_{1σ(1)}a_{2σ(2)}a_{3σ(3)} = \sum_{l,m,n = 1}^{3} \varepsilon^{ijk}\varepsilon^{lmn} a_{1l}a_{2m}a_{3n}$

where in the last step I tried to make use of the fact that $\varepsilon^{lmn}$ is $0$ whenever indices coincide. I am not sure where to go from here, or if this is even the right path to tackle this identity. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The statement is not ok. The left hand side is dependent on i,j,k while the right hand side is not. Please fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the determinant can also be written as

$$ \det M =  \sum_{\sigma} \epsilon^\sigma \prod_s a_{\sigma(s)s}.$$

Then $$ \delta^{ijk} := \sum_{l,m,n = 1}^3 \epsilon^{lmn}a_{li}a_{mj}a_{nk}.$$
is simply the determinant of a matrix whose

- first column is the $i$-th column of $M$
- second column is the $j$-th column of $M$
- third column is the $k$-th column of $M$

It follows that $\delta^{ijk} = \epsilon^{ijk} \det M.$

---

Another way to see it is that $$ \epsilon^{ijk} = \det(M_{ijk})$$
where $M_{ijk} = (e_i',e_j',e_k')$ is the matrix with the canonical basis vectors as columns. With this notation the equation your trying to prove is just

$$ \det(MM_{ijk}) = \det(M)\det(M_{ijk})$$